# Need to get value of a cell in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I cannot seem to get the value of a cell in a gridview to use in a stored procedure. Here is my aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="GridView" DataKeyNames="Check Config">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Config ID" DataField="Check Config"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Check Configuration" DataField="Check Configuration" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Shift" DataField="Shift" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Earliest Time" DataField="Earliest Time" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Alarm Time" DataField="Alarm Date" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Disposition" DataField="Disposition" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Disable">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RowLevelCheckBox" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And here is my code-behind wherein I'm trying to get the value of the first column/cell in the gridview for a stored procedure parameter. In this case I am looking to get the value of "Config ID" but get 0 back each time. It's been a while since I've been back into ASP.NET but this project calls for it.

```
try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow dr in gvData.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)dr.Cells[6].FindControl("RowLevelCheckBox");
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    recordCount += 1;
                    int theConfigID = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[0].FindControl("Config ID").ToString());
                    //cancel these alarms in DB 
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CHECK_SCHEDULE_ID", theConfigID));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //return status and msg
                    lblStatusMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
                    lblStatusMessage.Text = string.Format("{0} alarm(s) were successfully cancelled.", recordCount);
                    lblStatusMessage.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: does the gridview render with the value you want to fetch?

Comment: yes, the gridview is accurately showing the first column's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about just dr.Cells[0].Text?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using spaces in your column names and to use the DataKeyNames property on the gridview to access the id. This way you don't even have to display the id to the user.

```
foreach(GridViewRow dr in gvData.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)dr.Cells[6].FindControl("RowLevelCheckBox");
    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        recordCount += 1;
        int theConfigID = (int) gvData.DataKeys[dr.RowIndex].Value;
        //cancel these alarms in DB 
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CHECK_SCHEDULE_ID", theConfigID));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //return status and msg
        lblStatusMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
        lblStatusMessage.Text = string.Format("{0} alarm(s) were successfully cancelled.", recordCount);
        lblStatusMessage.Visible = true;
    }
}
```